# How to remove nbsp and add space in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to print a contex variable in django template.... my context variable name "content"

But this variable containing some html tags and &nbsp... This is my html

```
<div style="max-width:800px;margin:50px auto;padding:0 12px">
    <div class="m_-1931231161305542174card" style="background:white;border-radius:0.5rem;padding:2rem;margin-bottom:1rem">
        {{ content }}
    </div>
</div>
```

For example my user is entering this

```
Hello,

How are you?
```

that context variable containing

```
<p>Hello,</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p>How are you??</p>
```

For removing the html tag I have return one funtion

I have tried this method

```
def remove_html_tags(text):
    """Remove html tags from a string"""
    logger.info(text)
    clean = re.compile('<.*?>')
    return re.sub(clean, '', text)

def passing_contect(self):
-----------------
----------------------
-------------------)
context{'content':remove_html_tags(content)}//passing context without html tags
```

but the o/p is

```
Hello, &nbsp; How are you ????
```

It still having this &nbsp issue

How to handle this

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your function:

```
def remove_html_tags(text):
    """Remove html tags and &nbsp from a string"""
    logger.info(text)
    clean = re.compile('<.*?>')
    sans_tags = re.sub(clean, '', text)
    return sans_tags.replace('&nbsp', ' ')
```

This will replace the space with an actual space.